# How to set different subview in every section on tableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

guys i want to set different subview in every section, i put my different view into NSMutableArray, so i hope i can access it depend on indexPath.section, this is my code :

```
for (int i =0; i<promoCount; i++) {

    self.textView.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text view :%d",i];
    [self.arrayPromotions addObject:self.textView];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellPromotionIdentifier = @"cellPromo";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellPromotionIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellPromotionIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.arrayPromotions objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;


return cell;
}
```

But it doesn't work, subview just appear in the last section (but content of that subview is right).
iam sure that array have been filled by different view (by doing NSLog).
anybody can help me.????

Comment: You mean that cells in first sections does not appear the subview or appear incorrectly?

Comment: yes the cells in first section does not appear the subview, but the the cell in last section appear the subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What are you doing with y? Why divide an int by a float and store it in y?

Looks like you have only one `self.textView`. You are changing its `.text` member and adding it to the array multiple times but it is only one object and at the end of the loop you have multiple references to that one object, so all you see is the text it ended up with.

Comment: iam sorry, i have a lot of experiment in my code, but btw y is doesn't mean anything here, i forget to clear it '.'v

you're correct guys, when i write this
NSLog(@"first index : %@", [self.arrayPromotions objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"second index: %@", [self.arrayPromotions objectAtIndex:1]);
it's write a same text, :(  so should i alloc multiple textView for this case.????

Comment: Yes you would need a separate view for each. If it is nothing more than a line of text just use the cell's existing text label but I expect you want it to be more complicated than that. You can release the subviews you add of course as making them a subview causes them to be retained by the parent view.